# Is Elastic search filter in log stash work in synchronous or asynchronous mode?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-file, logstash-filter

I am facing one issue in ELK when I continuous log and tried to update some fields in log stash configuration file using elastic search filter plugin its updating logs sometimes but sometimes not working, so is there and load issue or synchronous or asynchronous issue and how to resolve it for apply operation sequentially and get proper updated log in output.